# Include desktop style post editing buttons within the android app (especially code format and picture upload)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, code-formatting, images

### Background

The mobile app is really quite good and I can see that a lot of work has gone into it. I also don't ever use it (except to send me notifications to my phone). The reason I don't ever use it is because the mobile site is really good as well and has very similar functionality.

So this request is based on including the key thing that is missing from the mobile site (and is probably difficult to include there); the post options at the top of the new post box.

### Feature request

Include the post editing buttons found on the desktop version within the mobile app, especially the code format and new image buttons. These are the two things which are difficult on mobile at present (my workflow for uploading images from mobile to stack exchange is really painful: email to self, save from email to desktop, upload to stack exchange).

This would give the app a significant "unique selling point" over mobile

[image]

Comment: If anyone can come up with a better phase than "desktop post editing buttons" that would be excellent